# How to call function from one class in another class

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 classes ThisWillWorkLayer and ThisWillWorkScene

ThisWillWorkLayer.m

```
#import "ThisWillWorkLayer.h"
#import "ThisWillWorkScene.h"


@implementation ThisWillWorkLayer


#define kSwipeScale 0.6

-(void) ccTouchMoved: (UITouch *)touch withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {


    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];

    NSLog(@"Touch at x:%d y:%d",(int)touchPoint.x,(int)touchPoint.y);

    [ThisWillWorkScene rotate:touchPoint];
}


@end
```

The ccTouchMoved function is executed whenever a swipe is made.  My error is on the last line of the function.  `[ThisWillWorkScene rotate:touchPoint];` it says the rotate function does not exsist.  However if you look at the ThisWillWorkScene class it seems like it does

ThisWillWorkScene.h

```
#import "CC3Scene.h"

/** A sample application-specific CC3Scene subclass.*/
@interface ThisWillWorkScene : CC3Scene {
    CGPoint lastPoint;
    CC3Camera* cam;

}

-(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint;

@end
```

ThisWillWorkScene.m

```
@implementation ThisWillWorkScene


#define kSwipeScale 0.6

-(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint{

    //CC3Camera* cam = self.activeCamera;

    // Get the direction and length of the movement since the last touch move event, in
    // 2D screen coordinates. The 2D rotation axis is perpendicular to this movement.
    CGPoint swipe2d = ccpSub(touchPoint, lastPoint);
    CGPoint axis2d = ccpPerp(swipe2d);

    // Project the 2D axis into a 3D axis by mapping the 2D X & Y screen coords
    // to the camera's rightDirection and upDirection, respectively.
    CC3Vector axis = CC3VectorAdd(CC3VectorScaleUniform(cam.rightDirection, axis2d.x),
                                  CC3VectorScaleUniform(cam.upDirection, axis2d.y));
    GLfloat angle = ccpLength(swipe2d) * kSwipeScale;

    // Rotate the cube under direct finger control, by directly rotating by the angle
    // and axis determined by the swipe. If the die cube is just to be directly controlled
    // by finger movement, and is not to freewheel, this is all we have to do.
    CC3MeshNode* helloTxt = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"Hello"];
    [helloTxt rotateByAngle: angle aroundAxis: axis];

    lastPoint = touchPoint;

}


@end
```

So my question is what is the proper way to call the rotate function from within ThisWillWorkLayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rotate:` method is an *instance* method, not a *class* method. To call an instance method, you need to have an instance of that object to call it on.

For example, this code would work with your current setup:

```
ThisWillWorkScene *scene = [[ThisWillWorkScene alloc] init]; //Get an instance, you might have to change this
[scene rotate: touchPoint];
```

If you wanted to be able to call a *class* method on the object (which I don't think is what you want to do), then you would change

```
-(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint;
```

to

```
+(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint;
```

Answer (score 3):

The method is declared as an instance method. You need to call it on an instance of `ThisWillWorkScene`.

If you don't need to make it an instance method, then declare it as a class method.

```
//in .h
+(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint;// Notice the plus

//in .m
+(void) rotate: (CGPoint) touchPoint{
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `[ThisWillWorkScene rotate:touchPoint]` is trying to invoke an instance method on the `ThisWillWorkScene` class.  For this to work, your `rotate:` method would need to be defined with `+`, as a class method, as such:

```
+ (void) rotate ...
```

Based on the content of your `rotate:` method, it looks as if it could be a class method.

If your intention is to use an instance of the `ThisWillWorkScene` class, then it would look like:

```
ThisWillWorkScene *scene = [[ThisWillWorkScene] alloc] init];
[scene rotate:touchPoint];
```